# OCR and text reading from image using asp.net core and visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ocr

I am working on asp.net core application. I have a requirement where user will take picture of machine from Iphone 8 and upload to server. I need to read serial number from that image. I haven't done this earlier. Some one suggested that I need to use OCR but for that I need to convert this image to Black and white first. Can you please suggest me free libraries/packages which I can use?

Comment: You can go through this article: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3220/extract-text-from-image-using-tesseract-in-csharp

Answer (score 2):

You should try **Tesseract** for OCR.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ocr-using-tesseract-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: The question is about "asp.net core", the link you posted is for .net framework

Comment: Support for .net core has been added.  https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/298